# Kubernetes Manifest File For Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am learning about Azure Kubernetes, I am basically following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-application

I am at the point where I am opening the Kubernetes manifest file, and I fell out out my chair and almost passed out. I'm a bit intimidated by this file. I am curious are these files created manually or is there a program out there that helps with this?

Comment: can you at least show the file (or link to it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major ways to manage k8s entities:

1) You can use CLI tools to perform various actions with your cluster, for example:

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image nginx
```

2) Alternatively, you can use yaml files to achieve the same result.

Create file with content like this

`apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80`

and execute this:

```
kubectl apply -f <path to your file>
```

Both ways will lead you to the same outcome.

You can find some additional information about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/object-management-kubectl/overview/)
Hope it helps.